# applying image texture to multiple objects

Tags: texturing, materials, windows

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpvh-9H8S1g) . But when I applied image texture to one cube it applied to the whole pillar. In the tutorial, he had to apply them one by one. Is it a new update or am I doing something wrong?

blend file- [image]

Comment: it depends how you created your cubes. Since u r a beginner, it might be a good idea to provide your blend file, then we can tell/help u.

Comment: You need to add _Material Slots_ as well as _Materials_ to those slots (The plus (+) button to the right of the material box adds a new slot, and the  plus (+) button below the box adds a new material to that slot). When assigning different materials, you must have a separate slot for each area that is different than the rest (A red and blue beachball, for example, will have 2 material slots - red in one, blue in the other - slot 1 (red) assigned to red areas, and slot 2 (blue) assigned to blue areas).

Comment: @Chris  I have added the file. please look into it

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I created the slot and now I need to assign this slot to every object I want but when I assign it to one object it gets assigned to the rest.